# What is the usage difference between properties($^) and src(edge) in NebulaGraph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I use the properties($^) and src(edge) functions starting from "2" over sell to find "1". But the returned results are different, as shown below.

```
(root@nebula) [basketballplayer]> go from "2" over follow reversely yield properties($$)
+-------------------+
| properties($$)    |
+-------------------+
| {name: "A"}       |
+-------------------+
```

```
(root@nebula) [basketballplayer]> go from "2" over follow reversely yield src(edge)
+------------+
| src(EDGE)  |
+------------+
| "1"        |
+------------+
```

[find a vertex starting from vid2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcX9F.png)

Can you tell me the difference in the usage of properties($^) and src(edge) in Nebula Graph?

Answer (score 1):

src(edge) always represents the src in the edge, and $^ represents the vertex from which to expand in the NebulaGraph database.